# Creating thread of object in different class

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn threading here. I have this demo class which prints the nth fibonacci number. No I am trying to create a thread for this demo object in another class threadtest1 and execute it. but I keep getting the following error

```
Starting thread :Thread[Fibonacci thread,5,main]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at threadtest1.startThread(threadtest1.java:21)
    at threadtest1.main(threadtest1.java:27)
```

### Can anyone help?

## DEMO

```
class demo implements Runnable
{
private int limit;
public demo(int l)
{
    limit = l;
}
public demo()
{
    limit = 10;
}
public void startDemo(Thread t)
{
    t.start();
}
public void run()
{
    int c = 1;
    if(limit>2)
    {
        int i,a = 1,b = 1;
        for(i = 3;i<=limit;i++)
        {
            c = a+b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Fibonacci number["+limit+"] = "+c);
}
}
```

## THREADTEST1

```
class threadtest1
{
private Thread t;
private demo d;
private int l;
public threadtest1(int l)
{
    this.l = l;
    demo d = new demo(l);
}
public threadtest1(int l1, int l2)
{
    this.l = (int)Math.max(l1,l2);
    demo d = new demo(l);
}

public void startThread()
{
    t = new Thread(d,"Fibonacci thread");
    System.out.println("Starting thread :" +t);
    d.startDemo(t);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    threadtest1 t1 = new threadtest1(5);
    t1.startThread();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a field shadowing issue

Answer (score 1):

change

```
demo d = new demo(l);
```

to

```
d = new demo(l);
```

as you should be initializing the field, not creating a local variable

doing so will prevent

```
d.startDemo(t);
```

`d` from being uninitialized

Comment: Yeah it's working, it's a silly error. Don't know how i missed it. Thank you